# Simplified coding of my calculator program?

Tags: java

I created a calculator that can do simple addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. I want to know if my program can get simplified bearing in mind that I am not that experienced with Java, I only completed a few tutorials online. Here is my code for my simple calculator:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Attempt1 {

    public static void main (String []arg){

        double fnum, snum, tnum;
        double answer = 0;
        int turn = 0;
        String operator = "nothing";

        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);    
        Scanner Symbol = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number");

        if (number.hasNextDouble()){

            fnum = number.nextDouble();

            operator = Symbol.nextLine();

            switch (operator){

            case "+": 
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    snum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = fnum + snum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            case "-":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    snum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = fnum - snum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    snum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = fnum * snum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            case "/":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    snum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = fnum / snum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You did not enter a number:");
            }

        }else{

            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        do {

            operator = Symbol.nextLine();

            switch (operator){
            case "+": 
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    tnum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = answer + tnum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }break;
            case "-":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    tnum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = answer - tnum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            case "*":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    tnum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = answer * tnum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            case "/":
                if (number.hasNextDouble()){

                    tnum = number.nextInt();
                    answer = answer / tnum;
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You did not enter a number:");
            }   
        }while (turn < 10);

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it work? Are you looking for a code review? Or do you have a bug with it and are seeking to identify it and fix it?

Comment: There's a lot of code duplication, and you should really only have one Scanner using System.in (plus, this question is probably better suited for Code Review)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review - probably belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. Java is object oriented and as such your code should be designed in an object oriented fashion. In the case of your calculator you have one method that does all the work. This is bad style because you can't reuse repeated lines of code. In your above example, you have the same code in two locations for every operator. Instead you should break that up into a parameterized method that can handle the arguments.

```
public static double operate(String operator, double first, double second){
   switch(operator){
      case "+": return first + second;
      case "-": return first - second;
      //etc...
   }
}
```

Your logic for retrieving the the numbers should also be a separate method that you can call as many times to retrieve a number. For example:

```
public static double promptNumber(Scanner scan){
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    if(scan.hasNextDouble())
       return scan.nextDouble();
    else {
       scan.nextLine(); 
       System.out.println("That is not a number");
       return promptNumber(scan);
    }
}
```

Using these two helper methods your code can be greatly simplified and much cleaner. Good luck!

Comment: As written, wouldn't your `promptNumber` stackoverflow as soon as there's no more doubles to read in?

Comment: I forgot to add the line that grabs the input regardless of what the user entered. My mistake, it has been edited to make this change

Comment: If it return the value, how would that number be assigned to a variable? Also the WHILE statement is crap. How can loop it depending on the user's answer? Also is the DO WHILE loop the best to approach it?

Comment: Whatever calls promptNumber can store the value in a variable since it will return the number the user inputs. Feel free to test the code if you are unsure about it. Your do while just checks the variable turn as it increments from 0 to 10. That sounds like a while loop would be more useful.